# Incorrect Results in my SQL select Query when parsing XML text column

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, subquery

Hi all I have a table that holds my business Id's and it is varchar(255) data type

I also have a separate table that stores an XML structured document in a text data type column when the business gets approved by a lender (it stores the companys information etc).

I am trying to return all business ID's that are NOT approved by a lender, the only way i can know this is if the business ID does not exist in the XML. 
I cannot join on any tables as i do not have any relational data, but i am trying to subquery it.

Any ideas? here is what i have

```
Select bus_id
From   dbo.tbl_business
Where  bus_id Not In (
                         Select Cast(company_xml_info As Varchar(Max))
                         From   tbl_company_reports
                         Where  Cast(company_xml_info As Varchar(Max)) Is Not Null
                                And company_xml_info Like '%Business id="' + bus_id + '"%'
                                And company_xml_info Is Not Null
                                And company_xml_current_status = 'Approved'
                     )
```

Comment: I am retrieving the same amount of records that i have business id's

Comment: You need to offer what the xml stored looks like.  I would not be casting it to Varchar(max) if it is legitimate XML.  I would cast it to XML if you are using SQL Server 2005 or newer and learn how to parse the xml properly.  It would be much faster than doing like statements and more readable in the end.

Comment: <CompanyInfo>                                                                                   
                  <Businesses>
         <Business id="A68">                                                                                                  
                       <Businessceo>"Test"</Businesceo">                                                             
                 </Businesses>                                                                                 
              </CompanyInfo>

Comment: Cool saw your update, I can work with that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example mark of something similar you can do.  This should run fine in SQL Management Studio 2008 and up:

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (BusinessId VARCHAR(8))
INSERT INTO @Data (BusinessId) VALUES ('A68'),('A69'),('A70');

DECLARE @CompanyXml TABLE (company_xml_info  VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @CompanyXml (company_xml_info ) VALUES ('<CompanyInfo>
 <Businesses>
  <Business id="A68">    
   <Businessceo>Test</Businessceo>  
  </Business>
 </Businesses>
</CompanyInfo>')
,('<CompanyInfo>
 <Businesses>
  <Business id="A70">    
   <Businessceo>Test2</Businessceo>  
  </Business>
 </Businesses>
</CompanyInfo>')

--Data as is
Select *
From @Data

--example of your code as is
SELECT *
From @CompanyXml

--exclusionary listing
SELECT *
From @Data
EXCEPT
--the secret of this is part 1 casting it to xml.  Then you extend that with '.value'.  That wants a structure to get to the Id.  
--I wrap that in ()'s then say the first instance of that [1] as in theory you could have more instances and do very complex parsing.
--Then it needs a type of sql to transform this value into
SELECT CAST(company_xml_info AS XML).value('(CompanyInfo/Businesses/Business/@id)[1]', 'varchar(8)')
From @CompanyXml
```

**Update 6-29-17**

If you have something that has repeat elements in a tree structure of your XML, I prefer the 'nodes' method of repeating them and then you do not have to worry about using a first.  You merely need to iterate through what you have from the use of the 'nodes' syntax and get a value like so

```
DECLARE @X XML = '<CompanyInfo><Businesses><Business id="C1405"/><Business id="C1408"/><Business id="C1408"/></Businesses> </CompanyInfo>'

SELECT 
  x.query('.')
, x.value('@id', 'varchar(8)')
FROM @X.nodes('/CompanyInfo/Businesses/Business') AS y(x)
```

Comment: this is great but it only searches for the first instance of my xml where it finds the busienss id, how do i have it search through my entire document where i have multiple business nodes, but this works and is great!!

Comment: You only provided one in your example and made assumptions.  Please provide a more complete example and I can parse as needed.

Comment: My apologies sir, how about this XML example <CompanyInfo>
 <Businesses>
  <Business id="C1404">   
  </Business>
  <Business id="C1405">   
  </Business> 
  <Business id="C1408">   
  </Business>
  <Business id="C1408">   
  </Business>
 </Businesses>
</CompanyInfo>

Comment: I am currently trying to fetch and loop through my document

Comment: That's not valid XML you are giving me now, I am going to make some assumptions again and provide an updated example though.